# MYSQL LEFT JOIN INCORRECT RESULT

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I'm stucked for a long while and unable to find whats wrong with my query, there is something wrong with my `debit column` in `LEFT JOIN` which is show in `Query Result image` in given below. The actual value of my `debit table` is `500` but `MYSQL` query display as `1500`. 
What am I doing wrong here. Kindly help me please.

This is my `customers table`

[image: customers` table]

This is my `cust_credit table`

[image: cust_credit table]

This is my `cust_debit table`

[image: cust_debit table]

`MYSQL Query` is given following

```
SELECT 
    customers.id as id, 
    customers.cust_name AS customer_name,
    SUM(cust_debit.debit_amount) as debit,
    SUM(cust_credit.credit_amount) as credit,
    (SUM(cust_debit.debit_amount)) - (SUM(cust_credit.credit_amount)) as balance


    FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN  cust_debit  ON customers.id = cust_debit.cust_id
  LEFT JOIN  cust_credit ON customers.id = cust_credit.cust_id


  GROUP BY customers.id
  ORDER BY customers.id
```

My `Query Result` is given following

[image: Result]

Comment: You are adding up the cust_debit.debit_amount columns, for customer one there are 3 records with 500 value. results in 1500

Comment: **SELECT 
 customers.id as id, 
 customers.cust_name AS customer_name,
    SUM(cust_debit.debit_amount) as debit

   
    
    FROM customers
  LEFT JOIN  cust_debit  ON customers.id = cust_debit.cust_id

  
  
  GROUP BY customers.id
  ORDER BY customers.id**

than why this works fine ?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple rows in the credit table, this makes multiple rows before the group by which causes the problem.  You can see this if you take out the group by and select all columns.

If you group by in a sub join this problem goes away then you have one row per customer before the group by.

```
SELECT 
  customers.id as id, 
  customers.cust_name AS customer_name,
  SUM(cust_debit.debit_amount) as debit,
  SUM(cust_credit.credit_amount) as credit,
  (SUM(cust_debit.debit_amount)) - (SUM(cust_credit.credit_amount)) as balance
FROM customers
LEFT JOIN cust_debit  ON customers.id = cust_debit.cust_id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT cust_id, sum(credit_amount) as credit_amount)
  from cust_credit
  group by cust_id
) cust_credit ON customers.id = cust_credit.cust_id
GROUP BY customers.id
ORDER BY customers.id
```

Comment: still same issue , not working still... :( help me out please !

Comment: @newbiee how is it not working what is your test data what are your results