# Cannot read from a file, weird behavior

Tags: c++, macos, clion

I'm trying to read all the lines of a given file. 
For some reason, `std::getline` doesn't work as expected. 
main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    std::string filePath = "../init.txt";
    std::ifstream inputFile(filePath);
    std::string str;
    int i = 0;
    while (std::getline(inputFile,str)) {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        i++;
    }
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    inputFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

../init.txt:

```
Game
battlefieldSize,100,200
players,2
soldiers,3
p1,human
normal,[2 3],M16
paramedic,[10 31]
sniper,[5 12],UZI
p2,computer,0
normal,[90 112],Missile
sniper,[90 113],M16
normal,[65 100],M16
Objects
weapon,M16,[5 5]
Armor,BodyArmor,0.8,[1 2]
weapon,Missile,[15 115]
solid,Tree,4,4,[20 20]
```

As you can see, I wanted to know how much times it's entering the loop, with variable `i`. The output is:

```
solid,Tree,4,4,[20 20]
1
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Can't duplicate on my desktop.

Comment: One of my friends actually had this kind of behaviour with `std::getline`. His code also was completely fine, but due to older version of IDE it compiled wrongly. Don't know how about you, OP, but if, by any chance, you are working on Code::Blocks and downloaded it from different source than original developer's, please redownload and reinstall it

Comment: Can't duplicate. Is there a problem with `std::string filePath = "../init.txt";`? Maybe you are reading another `init.txt` one directory level up?

Comment: j4nu5 - no its the only file out there, if I'm trying to read with `inputFile >> str`, it prints the whole file, but every space as a newline

Comment: Worked on my machine.  What OS are you using?

Comment: Eljay - MacOS
Ron - I'm working with cmake, cant do that

Comment: Your data file has the wrong kind of newlines in it. It uses `CR` as the newline, but `C++` uses `LF`. So the entire file is being read as a single line.

Comment: I think Barmar has a very good guess.  I made sure I saved init.txt with LF line endings (which is the default on my system).  I've also tested it on macOS (10.13.2), and it worked there too.  I've installed the latest Xcode.

Comment: What does `cout << str.size() << endl;` show?

Comment: Barmar - `cout << str.size() << endl;` is showing 287. I've tried to invalidate + restart

Comment: From the command line, use `file ../init.txt` to see what line endings it has.  (If they are LF, it will just say "ASCII text".)

Comment: Eljay - the output is: `init.txt: ASCII text, with CR line terminators`

Comment: What happens if you add CR delimiter `std::getline(inputFile,str,'\r')`

Comment: @Barmar You should probably turn that into an answer.

Comment: @Killzone Kid - `error: std::getline(inputFile,str,'\r') - no matching function`

Comment: @Yinon you are not using C++11 or above?

Comment: @KillzoneKid yea.. this is from the cmake: set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file has <kbd>CR</kbd> newlines instead of <kbd>LF</kbd> that is standard for Unix-style operating systems, so `getline()` is reading the entire file as a single line. You can fix the file in `Terminal` with:

```
tr '\r' '\n' < init.txt > newinit.txt
mv newinit.txt < init.txt
```

Comment: What favor are you asking for? If you mean an upvote, I've done that.

Comment: I don't understand what you're talking about. What does that have to do with this question?

Comment: Are you asking me to help with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47780622/mysql-left-join-incorrect-result